# Why doesn't the super function work to get class attributes?

Tags: python, oop

From what I've read, the super function is used to refer to the parent class. But if so, how come this doesn't work?

```
class Parent:
    x = 5

class Child(Parent):
    x = super().x + 3

obj = Child()
print(obj.x)
```

Comment: Where did you you read that `super()` refers to a class? It refers to an instance, and only makes sense in an instance context (when called without arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `super()` without args will only work in an instance method. If you really need it to work without referencing the parent twice, then I would make `x` a `@property` instead. That way you can access it from an instance context:

```
class Parent:
    x = 5

class Child(Parent):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x + 3


obj = Child()
print(obj.x)
```

Comment: So from what I understood, the super() function is referring to the 'parent' of an instance, not a class if I'm not misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
class Parent:
    x = 5

class Child(Parent):
    x = Parent.x + 3

obj = Child()
print(obj.x)
```

->

```
8
```

`super()` does not exactly do that, the `super()` function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class. You can read more about `super()` [here](https://appdividend.com/2019/01/22/python-super-function-example-super-method-tutorial/).